# Executing screen on Mac OS X on Terminal resulting in a error

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-arguments, gnu-screen

I work on MacOS X 10.6.8 and I need to use the **gnu-screen** application. For this, I execute in Terminal the next line command to create a new session:
`screen -S newsession`, but that generates this error: `LoginName too long - sorry.` What about this error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem with OS X 10.7.4 / Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06 and a username of 11 characters.

There is a bug filed for the issue though:

[GNU Screen - Bugs: bug #21653, LoginName too long - sorry.](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21653)